# knockout validating multiple radio buttons

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am using knockout and knockout validation in my project and I want to validate group of radio buttons if one of them is selected. In this fiddle you can see my html how it looks like and js too.

```
self.inputModel = ko.validatedObservable({
        discountAmount: ko.observable('').extend({
            required: {
                onlyIf: function () {
                    return viewArray[1].bonusesFromCar() === 'yes';
                }
            }
        }),
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ppqxqqh/

I am having problems with showing one message for those radio buttons... If you could help me somehow I would be gratefull..

Comment: The fiddle you shared has a lot of issues, you have not referenced the knockout validation library correctly, `viewArray` is not defined..etc..

Comment: Yes I know because I didn't want to pase whole code here, it shows only the code I have... The issue is how to validate with knockout if one of the radio buttons is checked or not...